# Clearing Inappbrowser cache in Cordova

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

We have an iOS and Android application that uses Inappbrowser which calls a website, here is the code:

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
          cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.canassonandco.com/canasson/rider/wall', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,zoom=no');
        }
        );
    </script>
```

If we make CSS or other changes on the website, these changes are not always taken into account immediately, we have to clear the application's cache in the Android or iOS settings. Not all users can do this, these changes must be automatic.

If I add : `clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes`, will it work ? Or do we have to do it differently?

Comment: I tried using `clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes` but is has no effect. The cache is not automatically restaured when I open the application. Do you have any solutions to this problem? I have installed some plugins to clear the cache but it doesn't work. I still have cached data in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it does not work, you could always put a revision date on your link to your CSS file on your website, to make sure the old version is replaced

```
 <link href="index.css?v=2022-05-05" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Oh yes didn't think about that. Cool. Thx !